# maven create zip with jar and some more files

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I do not understand maven. Better use ant, but... I've managed to create jar (with, or without dependencies), I've managed to copy bat runner script close to jar but now i want to create zip with this jar and this bat. So i use assembly plugin and get BUUUM!!!! CADAAAM! In my configuration it happens so, that it executes parallel to jar packaging. I wrote assembly file:

```
    <assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>jg</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/123</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>assembly/**</exclude>
                <exclude>runners/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Then, I bound maven-assembly-plugin:

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>by.dev.madhead.lzwj.Main</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/resources/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                            <!-- <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef> -->
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Now I get this in `./target`:

1. runner.bat
2. jar_without_dependencies.jar (it is from maven-jar-plugin, right?)
3. jar_without_dependencies.jar

And the third angers me. It contains:[image]
And the 123 directory contains:[image]

As you see, I get jar with unpacked dependencies, EXCLUDED DIRS!!!!, and with dir 123, which is actually what I want (Oh! assembly plugin did that!!!).

I want to get jar with dependencies and correct manifest with classpath. As an option i want jar with unpacked dependencies (I know about `<unpack>false</unpack>` in assembly, but cannot get it work). I want to change /123 to / and get NORMAL JAR WITHOUT EXCLUDED FILES!!! I want two separate tasks to build jar and zip (is it done with profiles in maven??) As in ant, i would wrote something like this:

```
    <target name="jar_with_deps" depends-on="compile">
        <jar>
            here i copy classes (excluding some dirs with runner script), and build manifest
        </jar>
        <copy>
            copy bat file from src/main/resources/runner/runner.bat
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="zip" depends-on="jar_with_deps">
        <zip>
            Get jar from previous target, get runner.bat. Put them in zip
        </zip>
    </target>
```

Excuse me, if I am too expressive, but I am really angry with this implicit behavior. I am really stuck with this.

Comment: <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef> does not work too

Comment: Tried to delete <packaging>jar</packaging>. Does not work, as jar is default packaging...

Comment: Ok, got jar-with-dependencies work. But still need customization of it.

Comment: Rather than to write a shitload what you have done, write precisely what you want to achieve. I'd like to help but I stopped reading after the first paragraph because you wrote too much off-topic.

Comment: I want two separate "tasks": create jar with dependencies and generate zip with it + bat file from resources. Second "task" must depend of first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to achieve your goal:

1. option: Create two assembly descriptors, one for jar with dependencies and one for zip. Zip takes the newly created jar.
2. option: Create two more modules in your project: first modules [shades](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) all dependencies into one jar (or attach a shaded jar along with your main jar, save another module), have the second module depend on it and suck in that jar in your assembly. Your done.

Depending on the size and structure of your project, I would go for the safe way: option 2. This one is guaranteed to have the correct build and dependencies order. Option 1 violates the maven way somewhat.

Comment: When i make two assembly descriptors the second one (for zip) cannot find the output from first one. How can i specify their order?

Comment: The order is the same as in the one defined in the pom. Attach the second artifact and this jar is included as well. See the [`useProjectAttachments`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet) attribute.

Answer (score 10):

Just in case it helps anyone else, I found that this was pretty easy to do, at least for my basic needs. I was already using the Maven Shade plugin to build a jar with all dependencies included:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
  <configuration></configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

So when I ran `mvn package`, it would produce target/MyApp-version.jar, whereas I wanted a MyApp-version.zip containing MyApp-version.jar along with some other files (a README, etc.). So, I add the Assembly plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The above block refers to `assembly.xml`, which configures [the way the plugin works](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>release</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>target</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>MyApp-${app.version}.jar</include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>CHANGES.md</source>
            <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
        </file>
        <file>
            <source>LICENSE</source>
            <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
        </file>
        <file>
            <source>README</source>
            <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
        </file>
    </files>
</assembly>
```

(`${app.version}` is defined in the pom.xml `<properties>` element.)

That's it, now `mvn package` produces both the jar and the zip.

Answer (score 1):

I've made two profiles in pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>by.dev.madhead.lzwj.Main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>distro</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/distro.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now i am able to create simple jar (`mvn clean package`), jar with dependencies (`mvn clean package -Pjar-with-dependencies`). I also can call `mvn package -Pdistro` to create zip. But i need to call maven with -Pjar-with-dependencies before it manually. Except this, everything is ok.